# Extending class with ArrayList member to class with another ArrayList type in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to do this in Java, although I find this general programming question.

I have something similar to:

```
class SimpleClass1{
    public int x;
    //methods...
}
class SimpleClass2 extends SimpleClass1{
    public int y;
    //other methods
}
class List1{
    public String id;
    public ArrayList<SimpleClass1> list;
    public .... //some more methods
}
class List2 extends List1{
    ???
    public ArrayList<SimpleClass2> list; //Need this member INSTEAD of ArrayList<SimpleClass1> list
    //have access to all the List1's methods
    //have some List2 specific methods
}
```

So I need the `List2` class to have access to all `List1` methods, but also the ArrayList member of List2 should be of the subclass `SimpleClass2` - as I don't find natural way to do this I start thinking my design is basically wrong. But before I start changing it I decided to ask if there is a good way to do this?

Comment: Use generic for that and some AbstractList<T> as a common parent

Comment: This is one of those questions that should never occur with good OO code.  Your internal ArrayList should not be public--it shouldn't even be possible to make a mutable member public!  So you make it private.  You shouldn't get & set the array list directly (The general rule is Don't allow other classes to manipulate your members, instead provide business methods that manipulate them).  Your business methods shouldn't have the concept of "List" or generics, they should be manipulating "Invoices" or "Pixels" or some other business entity.  Once you are at this point, the problem doesn't come up

Comment: Sorry to post two comments in a row, but someone will object to the previous so I'll mention an explicit exception--tooling (like libraries).  These are difficult in Java (and it looks like that's what you are trying for.  I suggest not doing this off the bat, instead do the simplest thing that can possibly work to solve the business problem at hand and later, when you refactor and extract similarities into tools you will probably find, again, that this question doesn't occur.

Comment: Bill K, thx for your answer(s)! Actually in my real code my internal variables are protected and private, they are not public. And I do not directly manipulate them outside the classes, I do use "business methods". In my question above I have tried to simplify things. Also as you mention - I did the simplest things at first :) and now I am trying to refactor, and I am trying to split the 2 classes that I made (as simplest) into 4 classes  - to logically divide different types of methods. And now... I still come across this problem :)

Comment: @BillK 's comment points the right way. Access your list only via a method. Also, declare it as type `List<Whatever>` instead of the concrete type. That way each subtype can have its own access. Also, using generics should be productive.